# Joining tables in mySQL using INSTR()

Tags: mysql, join, instr

I have 2 tables to connect without matching id, as shown below;

**table_a**

```
id    name
1     moe
2     joe
3     bob
4     sue
```

**table_b**

```
id    accessid
10    moe99
11    joe53
12    bob51
13    312sue
```

i tried to connect/join these 2 table using INSTR(). Below are my codes;

```
select *
from table_a 
join table_b
on INSTR(table_a.name , table_b.accessid ) > 0
```

However, I got this

> ERROR: function instr(character varying, character varying) does not
>   exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You
>   may need to add explicit type casts.

I also tried to use:

```
select * 
from table_a
join table_b
on table_a.name like '%' + table_b.accessid + '%'
```

AND

```
select * 
from table_a, table_b
where table_a.name like '%' + table_b.accessid + '%'
```

but these 2 resulted as;

> Query returned no matching rows

Anyone can help me on this?

Comment: See CONCAT(), but I hope this is a 'one-off'!

Answer (score 0):

[`INSTR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) documentation says:

> `INSTR(str,substr)`
>
> Returns the position of the first occurrence of substring substr in string str. This is the same as the two-argument form of LOCATE(), except that the order of the arguments is reversed.

You are using `instr()` the wrong way around. You want:

```
select *
from table_a a
join table_b b on instr(b.accessid, a.name ) > 0
```

I find that this is easier to understand with `LIKE` (which you also are using the wrong way around):

```
select *
from table_a a
join table_b b on b.accessid like concat('%', a.name, '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message:

> ERROR: function instr(character varying, character varying) does not
>   exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You
>   may need to add explicit type casts.

seems to be a **Postgresql** error where `instr()` is not supported.
So use the function [`position()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html) (which works also in **MySql**):

```
select *
from table_a join table_b
on position(table_a.name in table_b.accessid ) > 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/azoRgtgWAwo8hKBsQv3b3T/0).
Results:

```
| id  | name | id  | accessid |
| --- | ---- | --- | -------- |
| 1   | moe  | 10  | moe99    |
| 2   | joe  | 11  | joe53    |
| 3   | bob  | 12  | bob51    |
| 4   | sue  | 13  | 312sue   |
```